# How to cast the List received in the primary constructor to MutableList so that we can delegate the class to MutableList

Tags: kotlin, constructor, casting, delegation

I want to implement the kotlin's MutableList interface by adding some thread safe features and if i want to implement MutableList interface and overriding only the stuffs which are unsafe for thread, hence I choosen delegation.

Every time using List.toMutableList() it returns a new Instance of MutableList containing all the items in data.

```
class ThreadSafeList<E> constructor(data: List<E>): MutableList<E> by data.toMutableList() //different reference (new object created when using toMutableList())
{
    private val data = data.toMutableList() //different reference (new object created when using toMutableList())
    ...

    //default constructor when no argument is supplied
    constructor(): this(listOf())

    //override, locks & stuffs for thread safety
}
```

**Expectation:**
I want to cast List to MutableList in constructor itself so that the implementation delegate holds for the same reference as the val data holds, but I am unable to find how to do so.

Comment: why do you want to write your own thread safe `MutableList`? ... the easiest variant is probably to just change the type of the `data`-parameter to `MutableList`. Casting isn't safe (or you could add an appropriate check, where it fails, if it isn't of type `MutableList`, but then why, when you can just ask for a `data : MutableList<E>`)... but my first question is the more important one: why do you want to write your own thread safe list?

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) or [`java.util.Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html) (e.g. the `synchronized*`-methods)

Comment: @Roland bro the List and MutableList are interfaces which is not classes... Both have same implemented class of java.util.ArrayList, https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt#L90 and listOf() calls it as well by Array.toList(). So it is a safe operation as at both time we are dealing with ArrayList... Well by the way I found the solution

Comment: where did I mention classes? In the end your solution uses `MutableList`... and my question (why do you want to write your own thread safe list?) is still open...

Comment: by the way... you ask for "cast" and then you just create new lists... if you want to cast, use `as` (see also [Type Checks and Casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html))...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I finally found a way to do it.

I'll explain how i did so, It might help anybody suffering from this problem,

```
class ThreadSafeList<E> private constructor(private val data: MutableList<E>): MutableList<E> by data
{
    // default constructor, when no elements are passed
    constructor(): this(mutableListOf())

    companion object {
        // constructor for a list to use its elements for the purpose
        operator fun <E> invoke(elements: List<E>): ThreadSafeList<E>
        {
            return ThreadSafeList(elements.toMutableList())
        }
    }
}


fun main()
{
    // this is how you call it
    val list = listOf("Hello", "World", "!")
    val threadSafeList = threadSafeListOf(list)
}
```

Here what I've done is maybe a hack but it works like a charm. This is why I love kotlin.

You can create the object as you usually do, the  in invoke fun is also not required to put in when creating the object as it is auto-done by kotlin compiler when passing a list to it.